# MPI One sided communication, Remote memory access for low memory

Tags: mpi

I have a matrix A and a bunch of vectors (b0..bn) which I want to multiply to produce vectors c0..cn. 
Using the std approach, with MPI will be  to make a copy of the matrix A on every process and distribute the vectors among the processes accordingly.

for example , 100 vectors b0..b99, among 10 processes(MPI_Ranks)

```
rank0:
c0=A.b0 ,c1=A.b1, ... c9=A.b9
rank1:
c10=A.b10,c11=A.b11 ... c19=A.b19
...
rank9
c90=A.b90,c91=A.b91 ... c99=A.b99
```

My problem is that A is really big and sparse  and make 10 or more copies will be a bad idea or impractically , simply it wont fit (lets say I have a quad core i.e. in my host I will have to copy A four times, when one copy barely fits).

Would it be possible to use MPI one-sided communication to have A in process 0 and the other 9 Processors just read A using RMA and still produce c0..c99? like

```
rank0:
c0=A.b0 ,c1=A.b1, ... c9=A.b9

rank1:
c10=(remote A in Rank 0).b10, c11=(remote A in Rank 0).b11 ... c19= (remote A in Rank 0).b19
...
rank9
c90=(remote A in Rank 0).b90,c91=(remote A in Rank 0).b91 ... c99=(remote A in Rank 0).b99
```

Comment: If you're in a shared memory environment (aka your laptop), you should really be using a shared memory parallel programming paradigm (aka OpenMP). MPI is most useful as a distributed memory parallel programming paradigm (aka across multiple compute nodes of a network).

Comment: The answer is yes, it is possible. But the question is whether this helps, as you would still be stuck with a single process requiring this large memory? Wouldn't it be better to also distribute the Matrix? You could still make use of One-Sided if you want but just getting the data from different processes.